# Connecting from Oracle to Postgres using DB LINK gives NativeErr 202

Tags: oracle, postgresql, dblink

I followed the instructions [here](https://dbaspot.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/how-to-access-postgresql-from-oracle-database/) to connect from inside an Oracle DB client to a PostgreSQL server and execute queries on Postgres tables.

**Oracle version:** Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit

**Postgres version:** PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2, 64-bit

The error I am getting when I run a query like this

```
select * from "myschema.mytable"@PG_LINK
```

from Oracle client is:

```
ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
connction string lacks some options {08001,NativeErr = 202}
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from PG_LINK
```

(Would have been nice if the developers who built this had the common sense to say which options are missing and where the connection string is, rather than saying "some options"!)

I am able to connect from the Oracle DB server to the Postgres server using psql command, so connectivity is not an issue.

I even updated pg_hba.conf on the Postgres server to give explicit access to the Oracle server like this:

```
# added to test Oracle's PG LINK
host    all     all     10.XX.XXX.XXX/32       md5
# added to test Oracle's PG LINK
host    all     all     192.XXX.XX.X/32        md5
```

and restarted the Postgres server. (The address beginning with `10.` is the internal server IP and `192.` is the public IP of the Oracle server.)

I changed authentication from `md5` to `trust`, restarted Postgres, restarted the Oracle listener, deleted and recreated the DB LINK once again, but the same error is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the unixODBC driver and the `odbcinst_64 -j`, `isql_64` tools.

Check the "DRIVERS" and the "USER DATA SOURCES" files.

> odbcinst_64 -j
>
> DRIVERS............: /.../odbcinst.ini
>
> USER DATA SOURCES..: /.../.odbc.ini

Then `isql_64 -v DNS UID PWD`

Note that with the dg4odbc you should use the 64-bit driver.

Best regards,

S.